django-ninja: no Response object generated for ASGI api route
I'm running Django under ASGI and have basic api routes working fine. But when I follow the django-ninja documentation for an api route using a Schema response, I get this error:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'status_code'
I've tried different versions of Django, Python, django-ninja with no success.
Details are at https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja/issues/1168
